# Django 1.10 path is on mount 'C:', start on mount 'D:'

Tags: python, django, windows, path

I wanted to add additional fields to a many-to-many relationship and I created a intermediate model called Contact ( the goal is to implement a system that allows the user to follow other users and be followed too).

```
class Contact(models.Model):

    user_from = models.ForeignKey(User,
                                  related_name='rel_from_set')

    user_to = models.ForeignKey(User,
                                related_name='rel_to_set')

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                   db_index=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} follows {}'.format(self.user_from, self.user_to)
```

I am using the User model provided by Django (from django.contrib.auth.models) . As this model is not one I created if I want to add fields to it, I should (or at least, I think I should ) add them dinamically (with monkey-patch) . So at the end of the models.py file I added the following code:

```
User.add_to_class('following', models.ManyToManyField('self', through=Contact ,  related_name='followers', symmetrical=False))
```

But I runned the `python manage.py makemigrations` I got the following error :

```
    Migrations for 'auth':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\managem
ent\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\managem
ent\__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\managem
ent\base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\managem
ent\base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\managem
ent\commands\makemigrations.py", line 192, in handle
    self.write_migration_files(changes)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\managem
ent\commands\makemigrations.py", line 210, in write_migration_files
    migration_string = os.path.relpath(writer.path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 574, in relpath
    path_drive, start_drive))
ValueError: path is on mount 'C:', start on mount 'D:'
```

After a quick google search :

"os.relpath does give you a relative path between two directories.

The problem you are encountering is that, on Windows, a relative path doesn't even exist if the two directories are on different drives (which is exactly what the error message says). "

But what is the solution ?
I am using Windows 8 and Django 1.10.

Comment: What makes you think that error has anything to do with the added field? In any case, you should show the full traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Full traceback posted . The error happened right after I added the code above so I am positive this is where the problem is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running `makemigrations` from another drive (not from `C:` where django is installed).

There was a bug with makemigrations on Windows:

- see [this Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27436),
- and the commit that fixed the bug:
  [makemigrations crash when creating migrations on a separate drive than where Django is installed](https://github.com/django/django/commit/f94ce0d21de484a5783a3dcb122dc51757ed225b)

So to fix this error you should:

- move your Django project (your Python code) on `C:` drive
- or update your Django version (to Django 1.11)

Comment: If I modified the Django code myself like in the second link you provided ( [link](https://github.com/django/django/commit/f94ce0d21de484a5783a3dcb122dc51757ed225b)  ) would it work ? I am concerned that if I update to Django 1.11 my project would not behave properly.

Comment: Yes it should work but it's a hacky fix. You will have to manually patch this `makemigrations.py` file again every time you update or install django (for example, when you install your project on another machine). However I guess you will need to run makemigrations only during dev, so it can be fine to use this hack.

Comment: Thanks for help !